# Why did India ban PUBG if it is Korean app?

Tags: india, trade

Why did India ban PUBG if it is a non-Chinese app?

Wikipedia reads [PUBG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayerUnknown%27s_Battlegrounds) (PlayerUnknown's Battlegrounds) is Korean app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PUBG is developed by a korean studio, it's true. But its parent company, [Krafton Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krafton), is partially owned (second largest shareholder) by [Tencent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tencent) - Chinese company which I'm sure you've heard of =)

PUBG Mobile (which is the app that was banned - note that non-mobile versions are not mentioned in the [list published by Indian government](https://pib.gov.in/PressReleasePage.aspx?PRID=1650669#)) is (or, well, was) the most popular of Tencent's apps in India. Note that many other Tencent properties were not banned, and it seems that choice was probably made based on popularity amongst Indian citizens - for example, Arena of Valor (a ripoff of League of Legends somewhat popular in India) was banned, while League of Legends (also owned by Tencent now, but not very popular in India due to the lack of Indian servers) was not; PUBG Mobile was banned, but less popular PUBG for PC and similar Fortnite (Tencent owns 40% of Fortnite developers Epic Games stock) stayed legal.

Answer (score 16):

They didn't ban PlayerUnknown's Battlegrounds [PUBG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayerUnknown%27s_Battlegrounds) in all of it's incarnations, PC, Console, mobile, etc. They banned the [mobile versions published by TenCent](https://www.cnn.com/2020/09/02/tech/india-bans-pubg-alipay/index.html), [a Chinese holding company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tencent). Most of the media coverage hasn't been specific enough to point out the difference.